# “Can't add destination store” Core Data migration error

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, migration

I try to perform migration to the new database model version in Core Data. The mapping model is successfully found by

```
NSMappingModel *mappingModel = [NSMappingModel mappingModelFromBundles:nil
                                                            forSourceModel:sourceModel
                                                          destinationModel:destinationModel];
```

but the migration phase

```
migrationSuccess = [standardMigrationManager migrateStoreFromURL:storeSourceUrl
                                                                    type:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                                 options:sourceStoreOptions
                                                        withMappingModel:mappingModel
                                                        toDestinationURL:storeDestUrl
                                                         destinationType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                      destinationOptions:destinationStoreOptions
                                                                   error:&error];
```

returns error

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134110 "The operation couldn\u2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 134110.)" UserInfo=0x96f0350 {NSUnderlyingError=0x96d94e0 "The operation couldn\u2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 134100.)", reason=Can't add destination store}
```

I have met many problems with migration before but no one looked like this. What is the reason for this and how to solve it?

Regards,
Michał

Answer (score 1):

The answer was simple. The source and destination store URLs cannot be equal.

Regards,
Michał

Answer (score 0):

Are you attempting this on the simulator or a device you've previously run the migration on?  Does the store already exist in the Documents folder before you run the migration?

Comment: I work on the simulator. The store (sqlite file) already exists in Documents directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is in your simulator. Try to restart it. Or u can delete you're app from simulator. After this try to compile it again.